# Computer slow down every hour during anacron jobs

Tags: 20.04, cron

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnone recently on a Latitude E6540.

Every hour, the computer is slowing down, and sometimes, completly freezing, and I have to do a hard reboot.

The syslog doesn't give me enought information, I just see the jobs running, and if I watch a streamed video during the jobs, the video is lagging and I have to stop it and wait a few minutes to get it back to normal.

```
Feb  6 20:34:30 mycomp systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Feb  6 20:34:30 mycomp anacron[26357]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-02-06
Feb  6 20:34:30 mycomp anacron[26357]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Feb  6 20:34:30 mycomp systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
```

Any idea how I can track down the issue?

The crontab:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

free -h before slowndown:

```
              total       used      free     shared temp/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       4,0Gi       5,6Gi       1,0Gi       5,9Gi        10Gi
Exchange partition:       2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

free -h after slowndown:

```
              total       used      free     shared temp/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       4,1Gi       5,5Gi       971Mi       6,0Gi        10Gi
Exchange partition:       2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

etc/anacrontab :

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: Anacron usually handles daily/weekly/monthly jobs, not hourly. Something is wrong. Please edit your question to show us the complete contents of /etc/crontab/

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Next, review what occurs in all the /etc/cron.hourly jobs.

Comment: Also, during the hourly slowdown, run `top` to see what's using all your resources.

Comment: etc/cron.hourly folder is empty :(
about top, I'm seeing chrome taking multiple 80% or less CPU usage, but it's not different when the computer is not slowing. it just happened 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Check again, using the correct path. Were /etc/cron.hourly *really* empty, your system would be hopelessly broken.

Comment: root@mycomp:/etc/cron.hourly# ls    
root@mycomp:/etc/cron.hourly# - ls returns nothing

Comment: So many questions: Why are you using root? Why and how did you delete all the contents of /etc/cron.hourly? There's clearly much more to the story.

Comment: I used root cause my user wasn't listing anything so i thought maybe root will do, I'm a newbie on linux, I wasn't aware of the existense of cron.hourly, so i'm pretyy sure i didn't delete it. also, i just had the issue 10 minutes apart, so i guess something else is happening it may be not related to the cron jobs. I'm pretty lost ;) reading lot of stuff about ubuntu, but after 25 years of Windows usage, I thinkk microsoft broked my brain.

Comment: Run `free -h` before and after a slowdown. Post the complete output of both in your question above.

Comment: According to the man page for anacron -----When  executed,  Anacron  reads  a list of jobs from a configuration file, normally /etc/anacrontab (see anacrontab(5)).  This file contains the list of jobs that Anacron controls.

Comment: Please show us /etc/anacrontab

Comment: free -h and anacrontab added to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want instant relief, use
crontab -e

then put a pound sign (#) in the first column of the line having the hourly jobs
then save your file.

There could be a misconfiguration in the run-parts command on that line.  I don't think it should have "-- report" in it, but that is my hypothesis.

regards,
mondotofu